# Truncate with Hibernate and H2 is slower than expected

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, h2

Using Hibernate 4.3.11 and H2 1.3.172 database

I changed code to use truncate to empty a database table rather than delete because delete was performing too slowly as the number of records in the table increased. However *TRUNCATE* also seems rather slow (aprox 30 seconds) I assumed it would work rather quickly and would not matter how many records were in the table ?

```
    try
    {
        session = HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();
        session.createSQLQuery("truncate table SongDiff").executeUpdate();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        HibernateUtil.closeSession(session);
    }
```

Comment: probably it might be the implementation of H2. but worth to measure the performance using JDBC (without Hibernate).

Comment: Have you tried `drop`? is it also slow?

Comment: No its not slow, but how to you drop and recreate a hibernate table without recreating the whole schema ?